# Deploy a MDE - auto update & Trusted Source enquiry

Tags: batch-file, ms-access, vba, auto-update

My backend is on a cloud server and my frontend will be a MDE file.  My company now uses Access2013 but when the database was being designed and coded, we were still on XP.

I am hoping to be able to email all the users a file which will enable auto-updating of the MDE.  The examples I have seen require access to the backend.  While I do not wish to reinvent the wheel, especially as my only programming knowledge is some VBA, I am hoping to create a file that will:

1. Check if the path C:\Program Files\myDatabaseFolder exists
2. If not then create it and copy the MDE from my department server (not the
   cloud).
   (Possibly also copy a self-certificate to get past the
   Trusted Source warning)
3. If Path exists then check the date modified of the current version
   against the version on the department server and retain the latest.
4. Then Open the Database

There are a few things I'm not too clear on - this file I would email to users and get them to put it on their desktop.  When they wanted to access the database, they would just run this - but should this be a batch file or some other form of executable?

Also, when I created the MDE and tried to open it, I got a warning:- "not possible to determine that this content came from a trustworthy source".  I do not want the users to see that on opening the file/database, so would a self-certificate be adequate or is there a way to create a trusted location?  I am hoping for as little user interaction as possible - not all are able to follow simple instructions.

Any advice or comments welcomed.

Comment: Tip: Have the database check for updates and replace itself. Create a second package (maybe a vbscript) to do the initial install. And don't email it, place it on your network and email the path to the file. Beyond that, I'd have to charge a consulting fee. This is a pretty broad question. Good luck to you.

Comment: As an option, your VBScript could copy the newest version of the front end to a local, already trusted location on the users' machine, then execute that. This ensures each user always has the most recent version. To prevent an `intelligent` user from simply running the local version directly, an internal version number in the `FrontEnd.mde` can be compared to a version number in the back end DB, and if they don't match, exit with a nice (or angry, your choice) warning.

Comment: Thanks guys - sounds like a strategy.  link to script that will install the folder in an existing trusted location (or ask the user to make it one if there is something I can find that will just give them a button to press).  Script will also download the latest database version and create a desktop shortcut to it.  Database will have an autoexec macro to verify that there is no newer version - if there is, it will replace the existing one and open it.  You've given me a direction to take this - thanks muchly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set this up in a Citrix environment but it should work with normal desktops as well. It is described in detail here:

[FE Deploy Method](http://rdsrc.us/GmsIoO)

The script, I used, happened to be VB Script and can be found here:

[FE Deploy Script](http://rdsrc.us/R1JaTD)

I didn't have to charge a consulting fee for this.

PS: If you meet a request for signing up at EE, you should be able to just browse past it.

Link to script:

[Download script](http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2014/03_w10/838456/RunPPT-Operations.vbs)

Comment: Thanks for the response Gustav.  I am not able to browse past the EE signup request.  I managed to view the text of your reply by going into the DOM explorer (F12) and searching.  I wasn't able to see the script however.

Comment: Sorry. I changed the links but I'm not sure it will make a difference. However, the direct link to the script should work. I can copy/paste if you need more.

Comment: That's Great Gustav.  Both questions show your answer - you can't get to the script as you need to expand the comment, which resets to asking for login details, but your link to the script above works just fine.  I'll have a read through and hopefully get to grips with it.  Many thanks!!